# Use $pull with $ne in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I wrote this command in **mongodb**:

```
db.getCollection('bnaTask').update(
  {"_id":ObjectId("5a2d21823be8c34e903245b7") },
  { $pull: { "status.events": { "event": { $ne: "mybnaCsvUploaderExecuted" }  , "time": { $ne: "2017-12-10T11:58:53.543Z" }   } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

and I want to know how to write it in java, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is Object in java. you are just constructing BSON objects to match their respective JSON counterparts as used in the segment.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", 73);
BasicDBObject event = new BasicDBObject("event", new BasicDBObject( "$ne", 
    "mybnaCsvUploaderExecuted");
  BasicDBObject time = new BasicDBObject("time", 
    new BasicDBObject( "$ne","2017-12-10T11:58:53.543Z"));
  Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();  
  map.put("event",event);  
  map.put("time",time); 
  BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("status.events", map);
  BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$pull",fields);
  BasicDBObject multiple = new BasicDBObject("multi",true);
  getCollection('bnaTask').update( query, update ,multiple);
```